# 5 volt small UPS design (review request)

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, ups

I'm designing small 5 volts UPS that would allow me to run on battery or 5V source.

If source is unavailable, step-up module takes power from battery.
If this 5V source is restored, then this source is taken for step-up module, but also battery is being charged

There are two diodes, so only one source will be taken to step-up module, by comparing voltages - 5V or from battery (3.7-4.2V),

I've decided to do it semi-DYI, so I used some ready made components, 

**but I'd like You to review these connections.**
Connection and modules in short:

- charger module is a widely available TP4056 module, available for few bucks. It stops charging at 4.22V and resumes charging when battery voltage below 2.8V
- Li-ion battery is a 18650, 3.7V one, scrapped from battery bank (no protection)
- two diodes shown on image below are Schottky 1N5819 1A / 40V
- at the output, I have step-up module that gives me a stable 5V/500mA source for devices connected

Is this module safe to leave it unattended, or maybe you would change something here, like adding extra protection, modules replacement ?
I used Schottky diodes, but since this is my first real electronic project (without the ones did for a fun and learn), I didn't want to complicate this design with PNP/NPN transistors. I need to know them more, or learn all theirs weaknesses first.

[image]

Comment: It appears that your diagram is not showing the "correct" connection between the battery (+), the charger output (+), and the diode connected to the battery.  They should be the same node.  this may cause the battery to overcharge/overheat.  Also, I would connect the battery to the chip rather than the step up module.

Answer (score 1):

The TP4056 module is good for charging but it's quite possible the step up module has a 20mAh or so quiescent current and it might drain the battery even when it's not powering something. If you're not using this for a very low power device then it might not matter.

In my opinion, a better option would be to use something based on [TPS61090](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61090.pdf) such as the [PowerBoost](https://youtu.be/CyZHkMZmFzc) board.

Otherwise your concept it's clearly cheaper if that is more important here.

Comment: good catch. I think I'll insert some relay module between 5V and charger. You mentioned TPS61090, but I forgot to mention that my goal is to make something DIY, but still keeping it cheap and safe.